# Button click is not working after Animation

Tags: android, rotation, android-animation

I have two `button` in one `LinearLayout` and inside this `LinearLayout` i have two button. When i animate `LinearLayout` then working fine but when tried to click on Button which is inside `LinearLayout`, click of `button` is not working.

I already searched a lot but not able get rid this issue.

Below code to animate `LinearLayout`

```
an = new RotateAnimation(angleRightHead, getRotateAngleRightEdgehead (), Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.33f);
an.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
an.setDuration(1000);              
an.setRepeatCount(0);                
an.setFillAfter(true);   
an.setFillEnabled(true);   
head_neck_ll.startAnimation(an);
```

and this code of XML

```
<LinearLayout  
    android:id="@+id/head_neck_idll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"  
    android:orientation="horizontal" >    

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/head"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="clickhander" />
     <!-- </RelativeLayout> -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/lumber"
                android:layout_width="49dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="clickhander" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backupper"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="clickhander" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and code for `onClickListener`

```
public void clickhander(View v){
    if(v.getId() == R.id.head){
        textv = head;
        v1right = mapRight.get(head);
        v1right = mapLeft.get(head);

        head.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clickroundcorner);
        lumber.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundcorner);
        backupper.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundcorner);
        backlower.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundcorner);    
        legside.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundcorner);
        angle =0;
    } else if(v.getId() == R.id.backupper){
        textv = backupper;
        v1right = mapRight.get(backupper);
        v1right = mapLeft.get(backupper);

        backupper.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clickroundcorner);
        head.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundcorner);   
        lumber.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundcorner);
        backlower.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundcorner);
        legside.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundcorner);
        angle =0;
    }
}
```

Check the image:

[image: Myrequirement]

Note: 1 and 2 both are in same layout. I want click listener on each with `layout animation`

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you show the code for `clickhander`?

Comment: check updated one..@eduyayo

Comment: Please try to clear animation after completion of animation using animation listener. use 'clearAnimation()'.

Comment: @MD please go through the question again..

Comment: I think the problem is that the animation affects the images and not the button... Can u click on the button where it was and not where it is supposed to be?

Comment: @HirenDabhi thank you for your idea. Actually I want both  animation and click listener.. Any idea ??

Comment: @eduyayo.. I am also struggling with same issue but what is solution ? Click of button working from where it was...

Comment: I think you `click` is working but animation is not working. Try to `Toast` of button id in `onClick`, you may have some problem with animation

Comment: The truth is i donno... But there're more people with the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318757/button-does-not-work-after-animation-android

Comment: Maybe changing the button x and y by code or creating another button after anim is done. Please, upvote this girl, some gross guy downvoted

Comment: `android:onClick` is for API level 4 onwards, so if you're targeting < 1.6, then you can't use it.

Comment: @eduyayo Upvoted dear.. You are right? Please understand question then up and down the vote.

Comment: @PratikButani  n eduyayo plz check the question.. Any idea how i can achieve both?

Comment: Check it with separate method if possible to you.

Comment: Use 'ObjectAnimator' if API level is >= 'HoneyComb'. otherwise you have to set LayoutParam of your view. refer this http://www.widecodes.com/0xzgeVejkk/button-not-responding-to-click-event-after-translation-animation.html

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this is normal behavior. This is because animation just rerenders `View`'s pixels, but it's position on the display remains the same.

If you want to relocate your `View` to the place where your animation ends, you need to call `View.layout()` method and pass these 4 parameters, which describe `View`s new position on its layout.

Keep in mind that `View.layout()` gets params relative to `View's parent.